# API access stopped working with "`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found."

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, api

I had a working application embedded in Google Sheets that read the Stack Exchange API for teams, using a noexpiry token. All of a sudden, one day, it stopped working with the following error returned:

```
{"error_id":403,"error_message":"`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.","error_name":"access_denied"}
```

I tried resetting the client secret. Heck, I tried registering a whole new application. It happily gets a new access token, but it refuses to allow me to use it. I would appreciate help figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your report. This has now been fixed.

We deployed an internal code analyzer last week that inadvertently blocked some API requests from finding (and thus hitting) Teams routes by stripping the `Async` suffix on action names. We fixed the immediate issue and will add some fancy monitoring so we can track this sort of problems more promptly in the future.